# How to make a div at right most corner?

Tags: html, css

How to make a div at right most corner without doing margin right or left ?

I tried to do by using margin left 300-400px but would like to know easy way to do

Comment: When you say right most corner, do you mean the corner of your screen?

Comment: There's a number of ways to achieve this depending on what exactly you're doing.

This will do what you're asking but may not be what you actually want:

`.my-div-class {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0
}`

Comment: Post the relevant HTML CSS codes so that someone can check your issue

Comment: I would recommend reading through MDN's [position documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using position: absolute

```
div.some-div {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    /* Or top, depending on which corener you want */
    /* top: 0; */
}
```

When using position: absolute, the top, bottom, lef and right properties will position the div relative to the closest parent that has position: relative. If no such parent is found, it falls back to the entire body

Answer (score -1):

You can justify right or left by giving a certain width to the div you want to justify right or left, then saying margin-left: auto or margin-right: auto.

---

If you want to fully justify the edges of the page, it will be enough to reset the margin and padding properties to the body.

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.box{
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:1rem;
  background:red;
  width:200px;
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Box</div>
```

Comment: The question doesn't give much information, but it does specifically say "without doing margin right or left"